# How to find the elements that have no relation (with an active status)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to find all sites who have no relation with an active statut?

```
Site.joins(:site_links).where("site_links.active = ? ", true).group('sites.id').having('COUNT(site_links.*) = 0')
```

For example,  I have a first site who have 5 relations. In this five relations, one is active. I have a second site who have 3 relations, but no one of this is active.
I would like to get only the second site.

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :site_links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, through: :site_links
end

class SiteLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :link
end

class Link < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :site_links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sites, through: :site_links
end
```

Comment: What's your Rails version and how are your models related?

Comment: Rails 6.1.3 and I added the related model ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SQL NOT EXISTS`

```
Site.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM site_links
                        WHERE (site_id = sites.id)
                        AND active = true)")
```

Comment: Only the first one method return the attended result ;)

Comment: @Ben second one works for me. could you please share the SQL generated by second query.

Comment: SELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" LEFT OUTER JOIN "site_links" ON "site_links"."site_id" = "sites"."id" WHERE "site_links"."active" != $1  [["active", true]]

Comment: yes you are right, I removed the left_outer_join query from answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set has_many association properly you can do this

```
Site.includes(:site_links).where.not(site_links: { active: true })
```

Comment: includes loads associated records in advance

Comment: Why it's not necessary? we check if associated site_links is active or not. The related question is what are more performant includes or joins, you can find response in [this](https://medium.com/@swapnilggourshete/rails-includes-vs-joins-9bf3a8ada00) article

Comment: includes generate a query which contains a LEFT OUTER JOIN look at [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

Comment: The first one is correct, so I will update my answer, thanks @SebastianPalma